# Logging certain messages that both mention a user and have a emoji

Tags: python, discord.py

So what im trying to implement in my discord bot is something like where the bot will scan messages and if it comes across ones meeting certain criteria (in this case both mentioning a user and containing a moneybag emoji) the bot will take the entirety of this message and log it to another channel

Here is my code currently:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message: str):
    logchannel = bot.get_channel(785597501612752927)
    overlord = bot.get_user(763576957618618428)
    ts = time.time()
    st = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    if message.content.startswith(":moneybag:"): #checks for moneybag emoji at start of message
        if overlord.mentioned_in(message): #checks for 
            await logchannel.send(content=f"{message.content}", allowed_mentions=None) #Stop double pings while still logging content
            with open("logs.txt", "a") as text_file: #backup logs
                print(f"<{st}> {message.content}", file=text_file) #only way that this works
```

I'm not too sure what is going wrong as when I match these criteria the bot simply does nothing. No log file is created nor message sent nor any errors thrown up. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: One potential issue: looks like message is `str` type. String doesn't have `.content` attribute. Otherwise, best way to test it is to print logging to console in each step and see if they are reached.

Comment: do you have `intents.messages` and `intents.members` enabled?

Answer (score 0):

The bot does not recognize `:moneybag:` as an emoji. Standard discord emojis are seen as the symbols. "" in your case. So

```py
if message.content.startswith(":moneybag:"): # Will not recognize the emoji

if message.content.startswith(""): # Will recognize the emoji
```

`on_message(message)` will pass the [message object](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message). It has multiple parameters we can work with. Tim pointed out in a comment on your post that a string does not have `.content` parameter, but `message object` does.

Because of the emoji, you will not be able to write to the txt-file unless you specify `utf-8` encoding. If you want the log to say `:moneybag:` rather than , you can have a look in to the [emoji module](https://pypi.org/project/emoji/).

`.... allowed_mentions=None)` won't stop it from mentioning. To set it, you have to specify according to [AllowedMentions class](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#allowedmentions).

datetime module has `datetime.now()` which will call the current time (UTC-time). So for the purpose of timestamp, you can just use `datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')`

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    # Since your bot sends the exact same message later, it would end up looping itself
    # So you need to stop the bot responding to it's own messages
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
        
    logchannel = bot.get_channel(742144472296718400)
    overlord = bot.get_user(748314853080301608)
    st = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    if message.content.startswith("") and overlord.mentioned_in(message): #checks for emoji and mention
        allowed_mentions = discord.AllowedMentions.none() # Set AllowedMentions parameter
        await logchannel.send(content=f"{message.content}", allowed_mentions=allowed_mentions)
        with open("logs.txt", "a", encoding="utf-8") as text_file: # Emojis not supported without specifiying encoding
            print(f"<{st}> {message.content}", file=text_file)
```